# как выровнять эту таблицу

Tags: c++

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int Cols, Rows, value, value2;
    cout << "Введите количесво элементов:";
    cin >> value;
    while (value<0)
    {
        cout << "Введите количесво элементов ещё раз:";
        cin >> value;
    }
    cout << "Введите количесво количесво элементов в столбцe:";
    cin >> Rows;
    while (Rows<0||Rows>value||value%Rows)
    {
        cout << "Введите количесво количесво элементов в столбцe ещё раз:";
        cin >> Rows;
    }
    Cols = value / Rows;
    value2 = Rows;
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
        {

                for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
    {
        cout << fixed << right << setw(3) << "|" << value2 + Rows * j;
    }
    value2--;
    cout << endl;
}
        }
        value2--;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чет не работает

Comment: добавил фото и изменил код

Comment: все верно, теперь символ `"|"` выводится шириной 3

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "|" << fixed << right << setw(3) << value2 + Rows * j;
```

Добавлены манипуляторы: `right` - для выравнивания колонки чисел справа, и `setw` для задания минимальной ширины. `setw` относится только к следующему после него элементу.